# How is the program of the Vienna New Year's Concert decided?

Tags: classical-music

On the [Vienna New Year's Concerts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_New_Year%27s_Concert) of this century, how was it decided what pieces of music are performed? Does the conductor of the year simply decide on his own after he is chosen? Or do candidate conductors have to send an election statement containing the program in advance, and the conductors are chosen after viewing that? Or perhaps there is program writer separate from the conductor for this?

This is a cross-post from [en.wikipedia Reference Desk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Entertainment/2015_December_19#How_is_the_program_of_the_Vienna_New_Year.27s_Concert_decided.3F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The female narrator from the Austrian broadcast station said this year that Mariss Jansons decided which pieces to perform after studying hundreds of scores. While this leaves open whether he did this before being elected or afterwards, I can't imagine him spending an effort like this into the blue.